# How to set default sort order for custom listing uicomponent to use multiple columns

Tags: magento2.2, grid, uicomponent, listing

I created a custom admin grid using a lising uicomponent. I want the initial sort order to sort by 2 columns. This does the trick in the grid's Collection class for the initial page load of the grid:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();

    $this->setOrder('zone_name', 'asc');
    $this->setOrder('zip', 'asc');

    return $this;
}
```

However, if you then sort the column in the admin by clicking any column header, it always maintains the above sorting.

I found that if instead of doing the above, I can set the default sort order in the listing uicomponents XML file like this:

```
<column name="zone_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Zone</item>
            <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

The key line there is:

```
<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
```

That works fine, but is there a way to use that method and also sort by two columns?